# How to disable LegendClick event in HighCharts using the Objective-C wrapper?

Tags: ios, objective-c, highcharts

I am using [HighChart](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-ios) and there's 1 functionality to hide particular Column data when particular legend is clicked.

I want to disable that legend click event but not working. for that I have tried below code.

```
plotoptions.column.events.legendItemClick = false;
plotoptions.series.events.legendItemClick = false;
plotoptions.series.events.click = false;
plotoptions.series.events.selection = false;
```

**I have also tried below code.**

```
HIEvents *event = [[HIEvents alloc] init];
event.legendItemClick = false;
```

Please help me out to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Solution. Using below code I am able to disable click event.

```
plotoptions.column.events = [[HIEvents alloc] init];
plotoptions.column.events.legendItemClick = [[HIFunction alloc] initWithFunction:@"function() { return false; }"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function () {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
  },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6snkq5L3/1/

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick

You can also use `event.preventDefault()` instead of returning false.

Comment: same thing I have tries in my above code but it's not working. still the click event is working.

Comment: HIEvent doesn't have any properties like `preventDefault()`.

Comment: I didn't realize you were using the objective-c wrapper.  I haven't tried it, but the documentation is consistent with this solution. https://api.highcharts.com/ios/highcharts/series.line.events.legendItemClick.  Also, when you say it's the same thing as your code, it;s not.  returning false from the function is different than setting the function to false

Comment: Thanks for your answer. https://api.highcharts.com/ios/highcharts/ --> I looks for `preventDefault()` but there's not result like that.

Comment: I found solution.